# Need to find text in log file and send following five lines to text file using .bat file

Tags: file, batch-file, echo, findstr

I've been searching for a few days and have been unable to find anything regarding my specific question.

I have a log file I would like to search (using findstr) for the words 'Login Successful", once this is found I would like a time stamp, that entire line and the next five lines sent to a text file.

I've played around with findstr and tried modifying other suggestions I've found here but have been unable to figure out a way to include those following five lines in my output.

Thank you in advance,

Eric

Answer (score 2):

Download grep from UnxUtils
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

run:
    grep -A 5 "Login Successful" [log file name] > output.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Look for the line with "Login Successful" and output it
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "Login Successful" theFile.log') do (
   set skip=%%a
   echo %date% @ %time%
   echo %%b

)) > textFile.txt

rem Add the next five lines
set lines=0
for /F "skip=%skip% tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" theFile.log') do (
   echo %%b>> textFile.txt
   set /A lines+=1
   if !lines! equ 5 goto :EOF
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /a gate=0
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('type logfile.txt^|findstr /n "$" ') DO (
 SET "line=%%i"
 CALL :process
)
)>report.txt
GOTO :eof

:process
IF %gate% gtr 0 GOTO output
ECHO(%line%|FINDSTR /i /c:"login successful" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :EOF 
SET /a gate=6
:output
SET /a gate -=1
SET "line=%line:*:=%"
ECHO(%line%
GOTO :eof
```

Since you don't say whether any of the 5 lines following may be empty, the `findstr/n` method is used to reproduce any empty line.

Essentially, if the target string is found (I've assumed case-insensitive) then open the gate to allow 6 lines through. If the gate is open, the leading line number is stripped and the required line echoed into the destination file.